# Objective-C: How to override/replace classes in librarys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have to use a library "mylib.a" in my code, which source I cant access, though I know that there are some classes for e.g "NeededClass1", "NeededClass2". My problem is that I have also in my own code created classes with names "NeededClass1", "NeededClass2" and when I include both (the lib and my sources) I will get linking errors from the compiler.

I cant use the following options:
1) renaming my own classes into something unique
2) including only one of them (lib or my own source)
3) subclassing

Both have to stay. Would there be any option to "override" the classes in the lib with my created classes or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way to have the same-named classes in both your source and the library. And frankly, the fact that you're running into this problem means both you and the library author have neglected to obey the standard practice of prefixing your classes with a unique 2-3 character prefix (typically based on your name or your company's name, e.g. [Matt Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/) uses MG such as in [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine)). Your only recourse is to rename your classes.

Comment: Also if the classes are in you own source, you can let Xcode rename them for you. Just prefix them and you are done.

Comment: Yes. Well this is the thing. The author of the library uses an opensource code and so do I and seems that he has made some changes in it and not renamed the classes for his own use. So kind of a dumb was to rename those opensource classes for myself and when a bugfix or sth comes out, I have to do this again - but seems thats the only option. Thanks!

Comment: Along the way, Apple reserved two character prefixes.

Comment: @Justin: Technically, yes, though most people ignore that bit. If you're paranoid about future-compatibility, you should use a 3-character prefix.

Comment: @Justin: `OMGWTFBBQAppController`?

Comment: @Kevin Ballard more or less! =) background: he's developed an audio app/host, where many third party plugins are common. in that case, the risk of name collisions *is* much higher... but 9 is unnecessarily long even in that case (imo).